# Correct usage of SQAnalysisFileItemTypes

Tags: sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I want to analyze a C++ project created with Qt. But all header files that have a QtMoc tag in the .vcxproj file are ignored.

For example:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <QtMoc Include="SOMECLASS.h">
    </QtMoc>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I think its because this tool only recognize the following tags: Compile; Content; EmbeddedResource; None; ClCompile; ClInclude; Page; TypeScriptCompile

So I wanted to add another tag with the following command:

```
/d:"sonar.SQAnalysisFileItemTypes=$(SQAnalysisFileItemTypes);QtMoc"

OR

/d:"SQAnalysisFileItemTypes=$(SQAnalysisFileItemTypes);QtMoc"
```

Both are not working. Can someone give me a hint what the correct syntax must look like? Is it even possible to control this with the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was cross-posted and answered [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/4sw1rztKUKA/r96zyn2wCAAJ;context-place=forum/sonarqube).